# How to iterate over all crontab jobs and print the jobs' schedules, commands and comments

Tags: python, cron

I've got the following .py code

```
from crontab import CronTab
...
searchResultsList = cron.find_command('bar')
for eachJob in searchResultsList:
    print("Found this job", eachJob.command, eachJob.comment)
```

When I eyeball the `crontab -l`, I can see the .py is finding the jobs it should, but how can I get the .py program to access the schedule rules (*/10 2-4 0 4 *) of each job?  Something like `eachJob.rules` or `eachJob.schedule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Access cron expression (schedule) of each crontab job.

### Solution

There are multiple solutions depending on what you want to do with the cron expression next.

#### 1. Outside of Python, with [grep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

`crontab -l | grep 'bar'`

and the result would be something like this:

```
0 10 * * * bash bar.sh
0 23 * * * bash bar.sh
```

#### 2. Within Python, sticking with the [`python-crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) package

2.1 You could print `eachJob` when you iterate through searchResultsList:

```py
for eachJob in searchResultsList:
    print("Found this job", eachJob)
```

and the result would be something like this:

```
Found this job  0 10 * * * curl -X GET https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/event/with/key
Found this job  0 23 * * * curl -X GET https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/event/with/key
```

2.2 If you would like to access the schedule rules alone with 'python-crontab', according to [Get attribute from existing cron (#72) · Issues · Martin Owens / python-crontab · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/-/issues/72), you can do:

```py
for eachJob in searchResultsList:
    print(eachJob[0], eachJob[1], eachJob[2], eachJob[3], eachJob[4])
```

and the result would be something like:

```
0 10 * * *
0 23 * * *
```

Comment: Thank you.  Works as needed.